# ConcurrentDictionary AddOrUpdate method throwing IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, multithreading, hashset, concurrentdictionary

Jobs are getting added to the `HashSet` by different threads and throwing this error. Is there any solution for this ?

```
ConcurrentDictionary<myKey, HashSet<Job>> _dictKeyJob;

_dictKeyJob.AddOrUpdate(myKey, key =>
{
    return new HashSet<Job>({ Job };
}, (key, hashJobs) =>
{
    if (Job.Status == eStatus.Cancelled)
    {
        hashJobs.Remove(Job);
    }
    else
    {
        hashJobs.Add(Job);
    }
    return hashJobs;
});
```

Exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.SetCapacity(Int32 newSize, Boolean forceNewHashCodes)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T value)
   at Raj.OPS.Common.Test.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<SetOrAddKey>b__1(mKey key, HashSet`1 hashJobs) in 
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.**AddOrUpdate**(TKey key, Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the add to dictionary method?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. My crystal ball suggests that you are storing a `HashSet` as the values inside a `ConcurrentDictionary`. A `ConcurrentDictionary` does not magically make a `HashSet` thread-safe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307131/indexoutofrangeexception-when-adding-to-hashsett is likely the appropriate duplicate.

Comment: Just added the exact code.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the [`ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_AddOrUpdate__0_System_Func__0__1__System_Func__0__1__1__) method:

> For modifications and write operations to the dictionary, `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` uses fine-grained locking to ensure thread safety. (Read operations on the dictionary are performed in a lock-free manner.) However, the `addValueFactory` and `updateValueFactory` delegates **are called outside the locks** to avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a lock. Therefore, `AddOrUpdate` is not atomic with regards to all other operations on the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` class.

(emphasis added)

So you can't use `HashSet` as the value of the `ConcurrentDictionary`, and update it from multiple threads without protection. It will become corrupted, and start throwing random exceptions like the ones you observe. You should either protect it with a lock (using a different locking object for each `HashSet` to reduce contention), or use a [concurrent `HashSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922985/concurrent-hashsett-in-net-framework) (there is no `ConcurrentHashSet` class so you must use a nested `ConcurrentDictionary`).

Regarding the first option, the one involving a `lock`, you should use the same locking object everywhere you access the same `HashSet`, not only inside the
callback of the `AddOrUpdate` method.

It is possible though that all this synchronization that adds overhead to your application could be removed by using a workflow approach (the approach favored by the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library). Or it may not be possible. It depends on the specifics of what you are doing.